# List emails of clients accounts on Google Apps

Tags: api, gmail, google-apps, google-account

You will have to excuse my confusion here...

Basically, we have clients with hosted accounts and I need to somehow get a list of emails per domain name.

Say, `test.com` is a Google hosted account and that it uses Google's email service for `admin@test.com`, and several more, how can I find (programmaticaly) this complete list of emails?

I've looked around for a while and it only brought more confusion. I think my question relates to this [Google API document](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html#Retrieving).

While I'm usually armed with at least one line of code, I'm really clueless on this issue. Perhaps someone out there might shed light on this issue.

**PS:** I also tried [Google API Explorer](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/), but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Google Apps Reporting API and get the Accounts report. Of-course, OAuth is recommended auth approach.

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html#Accounts_Report

Provisioning API can also perform the same task and with a real time list of users:
http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/provisioning_API_v2_developers_guide.html#Retrieving_Users_in_a_Domain

But, its going to be slower for bigger domains since its a paginated feed. Reporting API on the other downloads a CSV file.